# How to display 0 in all the columns in a table when sum returned for all the columns is 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I am getting Blank columns But I want 0 Here as shown in the image. [Click here for the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prgvS.png). Below is my query and I want all the columns to display 0 when sum returned is 0.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Inserted,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pending,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failure 
FROM [dbo].[ETIME_TIMECARD]
where cast(CreateDateTime as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
Group By cast(CreateDateTime as date)
```

Comment: I've just gone ahead and removed the tag spam. Please tag correctly.

Comment: Also why is that clause in the `HAVING` and not the `WHERE`?

Comment: @Lamu - It is group by thats why having.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the clause `cast(createdatetime as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`, which has *no* aggregation, is in the `HAVING`. It should be in the `WHERE`. Also have a read of [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea); I suggest using date boundaries rather than casting your column.

Comment: @Larnu I got your point. I will use where here. That will make more sense.

Comment: Considering you've added a real table name which is belongs to the `dbo` schema, this suggest you are using SQL Server. Please ensure when tagging in the future you tag just the product you are really using. Tag spam doesn't help us help you it makes it harder, as we don't know what dialect/language you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting no results because your `WHERE` isn't returning any results and you have a `GROUP BY` with nothing to group on. In truth, the `GROUP BY` appears to not be required.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Inserted,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS Pending,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS Completed,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS Failure 
FROM [dbo].[ETIME_TIMECARD]
WHERE CreateDateTime >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  AND CreateDateTime < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AS date);
```

Though, personally, I would switch to a `COUNT` as you clearly are counting, and then you don't need to `ISNULL`, as a `COUNT` will not return `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Inserted,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS Pending,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS Completed,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS Failure 
FROM [dbo].[ETIME_TIMECARD]
WHERE CreateDateTime >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  AND CreateDateTime < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AS date);
```

Comment: I know there are no results but I want 0 instead of Blank table that I am Getting. That is my point.

Comment: The above won't return a blank result though, @SakshamSrivastava .

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your query, my bad.  This Solved the Purpose. Thanks Man.

Comment: I've updated to a more succinct version with `COUNT` though, @SakshamSrivastava . In my opinion if you're *counting* the number of rows using `COUNT` makes more sense, and you can't get `NULL`.

Comment: WIll THis query return all the records for the today's date?

Comment: That's what the `WHERE` is for, @SakshamSrivastava ...

Comment: Ok Thanks. I am actually a beginner at SQL so Apologies for stupid questions.